# Apache connection time out or rejected

Tags: apache-http-server, iptables, ubuntu-16.04, ufw

My father and I host several websites from an Ubuntu desktop machine.
He replaced his router and suddenly the websites weren't loading. the IP address had changed. It seemed to me that Comcast's silly xFi port forwarding system was not opening the ports, however, very rarely the page will load from an external machine but then the next requests will error out. So then I suspected it was some kind of DDoS or packet flooding either internally or externally. Any guidance is appreciated.

DNS: IP address changed in the @ records for the 2 domains. Verified DNS propogation occurred.

Router: verified port forwarding to the correct ip, verified reservation was set, tested with DMZ and without. Tried disabling the router firewall completely, no change.

Apache: can access the sites internally and SSL/rewrites are working. Tried binding apache to IPv4 only.

Ubuntu: verified the ports are still open on the firewall. Updated the ip address in /etc/hosts. Verified the correct ip address in the networking section.
uninstalled UFW and flushed all ip tables just to ensure there wasn't some weird chain that was blocking. Used netstat and lsof to verify the service was running, and listening and nothing else was binding to port 80 or 443.

Other: Use yougetsignal to check the ports, port 80 was reporting closed. Called comcast and after several escalations they opened a case, they called back and said they were definitely not blocking port 80. I used nmap and it was also reporting port 80 was closed on our domain and external ip, it reported open on the gateway and server machine's internal ip. My father replaced the modem again and that has improved but the pages still do not load. He replaced a switch in the house as well.

Update 8:35pm We have replaced the router and still have the issue.
I completely reconfigured Apache from scratch and the issue persists.
We put the modem in bridge mode, configured a separate linksys router and the issue persists..

Update 10:26pm We Factory reset everything and disconnected everything except the server machine to rule out any broadcast floods or DHCP / ipstack feedback or loops. Nothing. We also put the comcast modem into the factory settings and did not change anything. I redid my entire networking scheme to match what their defaults were (10.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.0.1) and the issue still happens. I still suspect the xFi remote management is blocking ports when it shouldn't be.. we've had this issue before and tons of people report this issue on their forums.

Comment: Having ruled everything else out you should be raising this with Comcast support ...

Comment: replaced the modem a third time and the issue was resolved until sometime last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the culprit. xFi has a threat monitoring service that was enabled and once disabled it stopped filtering traffic. It's pretty sad we called 5 times and had a tech out with nobody realizing this..

Comment: I was going to mention this.  xFi likes to block any traffic that seems unusual for a home network.